# How do I create a summary that is grouped by years first and then months in Views using contextual filters?

Tags: 7, views

Instead of the default formatted result of «Created year + month»:

```
 - Diciembre 2014 (12) 
 - Noviembre 2014 (20) 
 - Octubre 2014 (23) 
 - ...
 - Diciembre 2013 (13) 
 - Noviembre 2013 (34)
```

I would prefer something like:

```
2014
 - December (15)
 - November (14)
 - October (12)
 - ....

2013
 - December (19)
 - November (21)
 - October (13)
 - ....
```

I'm using Drupal 7.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Yearly Archive with month in drupal7](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/131528/yearly-archive-with-month-in-drupal7)

Answer (score 0):

In Views you can group results (e.g., by year), which can be found in the format settings. Within each group, the results are sorted according to your sorting criteria.

Although not exactly the same question, I think the answer of [Views: how to ASC sort the grouping field #1 and sort DESC its content?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/71767/views-how-to-asc-sort-the-grouping-field-1-and-sort-desc-its-content) is still applicable to your question.